# why am I getting 00:00:00 at the end of the date in the datatable? asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, date, datetime

Hi I am executing a stored procedure from the function below. On all the dates, I am getting time at the end 19:12:2012 00:00:00 in the datatable. The column is defined as Date in the database and return as Date in the SP. Why am I getting 00:00:00 at the end of the dates?

Thanks.

Sample code.

```
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
    Dim con As New SqlConnection(_conString)
    Dim SelectCommand As New SqlCommand()

        With SelectCommand                

            .Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter(_strAcademicYear, SqlDbType.Int))
            .Parameters(_strAcademicYear).Value = _AcademicYear

            .CommandText = "[Teacher].[GetDate]"
            .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            .Connection = con
        End With

        da.SelectCommand = SelectCommand
        con.Open()
        da.Fill(dt)
        con.Close()
```

Comment: Thanks, I am binding the datatable to a gridview. Is there a way to show just Date on the gridview ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because in your datatable, it's a `DateTime`. There is no CLR type for just date. The default time for a non-time-specified date is midnight - 00:00:00.

You can use column data formatting for your gridview, I'm assuming - haven't worked with one in ages - to properly output the data you want to display.

Something like

```
<asp:boundfield datafield="date"
    dataformatstring="{0:YYYY-MM-DD}"
    htmlencode="false" />
```

and replace the format string with whatever you'd like it to look like, of course. =)

(Tag updated as per comment by chridam)

Comment: Just make sure you set the HtmlEncode attribute of the boundfield to False

Comment: Hi chridam, why do i need to set that ? can you explain me pleasess?

Comment: @Laurence http://forums.asp.net/t/1001482.aspx/1 The HtmlEncode property specifies whether field values are HTML-encoded to their respective string representations before they are displayed in a BoundField object. For example, if this property is true, a string value of "<script>" would be rendered as "&lt;script&gt;". If this property is false, the string would be rendered unchanged. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.htmlencode.aspx